# Platform independent system lock for command line program

Tags: windows, macos, unix

I have a library which runs as a command line program. I'd like to give the user the option of setting up a lock so the command line program can't be run twice - that is - if it starts up, it can't be executed again until it finishes, from any terminal session.

The lock should work for any user logged onto a system - I assume we use some atomic operation on a file, but what kind of operation would that be? It has to be failsafe. The user would be able to override the lock with a --force option, in case of some error.

Any ideas on how to implement this without having to setup any third party software?

*Potential implementation:* Perhaps the simplest way to do it would be to write a file to the filesystem and delete it on program exit. Any program that comes in second will attempt to write the same file and get an EEXIST error.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create the lock file in some shared area and check if it exit before starting

Also make sure the permission on deleting files in that shared are only for a group of admins